# pg_fetch_assoc returns null

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a php login page that I already can establish a connection to the database. The problem comes when I try to login with an already existing user, I get a PHP Warning:  **pg_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given** . below is the whole query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (pj = $username OR email like '$username') AND password = crypt('$password', password)";
        echo "$query";
        $result_users = pg_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $query);
        if ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result_users)){
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: I doubt that `pj = $username` is correct.

Comment: Not only that, but interpolating variables that way is a SQL-injection vulnerability just waiting to bite.  Read up about **Prepared Statements** and why they are essential here.